# Is there any possibility to refresh VF page from aura component?

Tags: html, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, lms

1.I created a record for opportunity..
2.In opportunity detailed page..i edited the page and added LWC component,Aura component and Visual force page which contains **stage field**..
3.when i updated stage filed either from aura or lwc or vf or in detailed page it reflects in all frame works..
4.But when it comes to vf page every time i need to refresh my page to view the change ..
without page refreshing i need changed to be reflected in my VF page...
5.Is there any way to do it can anyone please help me with it..

Comment: Hi, how do you load data in your VF ? Maybe some existing code will help

Comment: hello...  to  load data in  VF page im  using controller because if im using standard controller its is throwing me an error..and if stage is changed in lwc component or aura or in detail page of opportunity or in vf page i should update in all frameworks..my issue here is if im updating the field in aura or lwc ..very time i need to fresh the entire page to view that change in vf page which i dont want..is there any solution for this ...it would be a great help for me...thank u

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard way to solve your issue is using the [apex:liveController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_livecontroller.htm) tag in your VF. This is in Pilot so the feature might evolve or be abandoned (not likely to happen).

You will probably use `action` or `oncomplete` attribute to solve your issue.